# How to create a function that calculates and retrieves a value from a table?

Tags: r, function

I have a table with info on driver infractions and value of infractions. I have two columns  Value  (of infraction) and year (of infraction).     For each year of infraction I have several values.   Years go from 2000-2014.

I need a function that can retrieve the total of infractions per a "predetermined" year.  I.e., when user types year, only get the info of that year. So far I can only manage to get the info of all years at the same time

I tried this:

```
total_year <- function(x=infractions$year){
  aggregate(infractions$value ~ infractions$year_deb, FUN=sum, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Then I type

```
total_year(2012)
```

and I get a table of infractions per year enlisting all years, but I only want the total for 2012.

My table looks like this:

```
       value year 
375714  1,00 2011 
375715  0,00 2012 
375716  0,00 2013 
375717  0,00 2014 
375738 12,00 2011 
375739  7,00 2012 
375740  2,00 2013 
375741  4,00 2014 
375762 23,00 2011 
375763 14,00 2012 
375764 18,00 2013 
375765  7,00 2014 
375786  6,00 2011 
375787  4,00 2012 
375788  2,00 2013 
375789  5,00 2014 
375810  0,00 2011 
375811  0,00 2012 
375812  0,00 2013
```

Comment: Do you want the total _number_ of infractions from that year? Or a list of the infractions from that year? Also, you'll have more luck getting an answer (and getting one quickly) if you can give a reproducible example (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)) for others to work with

Comment: yes, the total number of infractions from that year.    Ie: total number of infractions for the year (2012)   thanks.  I will try to reproduce the example

Comment: value     year
375714    1,00      2011
375715    0,00      2012
375716    0,00      2013
375717    0,00      2014
375738   12,00      2011
375739    7,00      2012
375740    2,00      2013
375741    4,00      2014
375762   23,00      2011
375763   14,00      2012
375764   18,00      2013
375765    7,00      2014
375786    6,00      2011
375787    4,00      2012
375788    2,00      2013
375789    5,00      2014
375810    0,00      2011
375811    0,00      2012
375812    0,00      2013

Comment: Formatted text and code, moved data from comment into Q, rephrased title

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using `dplyr`

**Data**

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(value = sample(c("speeding", "parking", "dui"), 45, replace = T),
                 year = rep(2000:2014, 3))
```

**Function**

```
library(dplyr)

total_year <- function(data, x) {
  data %>%
    filter(year == x) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarize(inf = length(unique(value))) %>%
    ungroup
}
```

**Usage**

```
total_year(df, 2014)
#     year   inf
#     <int> <int>
#   1  2014     1
```

Comment: Glad it's helpful. If you find an answer helpful, make sure to upvote it on the side.